# which languages to include in iphone app for creating localizable for both western and eastern languages?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, localization

i am creating a iphone app which i want to localize.

So which languages should i include in my app for creating localizable for both western and eastern languages?

i want to know what does the **western and eastern languages** means?

Answer (score 0):

Western languages are typically those spoken in Europe, Africa and the Americas, for example English, French, Portuguese, Finnish, Spanish, etc. They typically have a romanized alphabet. Eastern languages are usually limited to Chinese, Japanese, Korean and sometimes Vietnamese. They are usually pictographic languages, but don't have to be. You'll have to decide based on your own reasoning what languages you want to translate your app into though.